# ConverseJs modals not displaying properly when bootstrap 4 is being used already in website

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, converse.js

I'm pretty new to ConverseJs, so please be patient with me.I have set up a Ejabberd server, and can connect to it happily with the ConverseJs plugin.

However, when it comes to clicking any of the options that would display a modal, I am presented with the grey overlay (which is normally behind the modal) on top of the modals content.

I am already using Bootstrap 4 within the site, and have the bootstrap css file on the server.Is this just a case of adjusting the z-index of the modals content/overlay within the ConverseJs/Bootstrap css file?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a workaround here:

https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/issues/1240

Just add this to your pages:

```
.modal-backdrop {
   z-index: 1030!important;
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ConverseJs use Bootstrap Native, so every time you load conversejs, its Modal, Dropdown and others mess with your DOM attaching another handler.
I have the same problem, but not just only with modals, with Dropdown too and I still don't find how to replace Bootstrap native with Bootstrap.

Comment: Add this type of comment in the comment section. Not as an answer.